# simple SQL statement to find younger lover

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

```
People
id|name|age

Loves
id1|id2  //id1 loves id2
```

I need a SQL query that let me know all the id of people who are loved by id's of the lower age.

Till now I have written something like:

```
select name from People where ID in (select ID1 from (select * from People, Likes where People.ID = Loves.ID2)) < 
(select age from People, Loves where People.ID = Loves.ID2);
```

which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the love relation is reciprocal - [*amor ch'a nullo amato amar perdona*](https://www.quora.com/What-did-Dante-mean-by-Amor-cha-nullo-amato-amar-perdona) - then you can use Martin Smith's answer.

If the relation is directional, and P1 may love P2 without being loved in return, then this becomes

```
SELECT loved.id, COUNT(*) AS lovers
    FROM People AS lover
    JOIN Loves  AS loves  ON (lover.id = loves.id1)
    JOIN People AS loved  ON (loves.id2 = loved.id)
 WHERE lover.age < loved.age
 GROUP BY loved.id;
```

## Explanation

We start selecting people who love other people:

```
SELECT ... FROM People AS lover
```

Then we add the relation of which they're part:

```
... JOIN loves ON (lover.id = loves.id1)
```

Since we need the loved one's age, we needs must join with People again:

```
... JOIN People AS loved ON (loves.id2 = loved.id)
```

This above is *all* the non-lonely people. We need to restrict to those with a lover younger than themselves,

```
WHERE lover.age < loved.age
```

(we could disregard Woody Allen's wisdom and add `AND loves.id1 != loves.id2`)

But now we discover that people loved by more than one person will appear several times in the output. There's no way of avoiding this, as they *are* more than once in the Loves table.

So what we do is either use DISTINCT to suppress duplicate rows (this was Martin Smith's idea) or try to exploit the situation by using the additional information - [we can *count* the lines](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/how-do-i-love-thee-sonnet-43) by grouping on the loved's id:

```
SELECT loved.id, COUNT(*) AS lovers...
```

Comment: It is a directional relation and I liked your mention of amor ch'a nullo amato amar perdona.

Comment: Ah I completely missed the comment `//id1 loves id2`

Comment: @MartinSmith , so did I. I upvoted your answer because I had started writing one myself, and I had written your exact same query :-D. *Then* I went looking if I might add anything original.

Comment: @LSerni Could you explain your SQL statement a little

Comment: Not sure if this is what you were looking for - the original query seemed self explanatory enough to me. Perhaps you need adding some information to the question...?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way (not as clean as @MartinSmith 's):

```
select id2
from
(select id1
       ,p.age as lover_age
       ,id2
       ,p2.age as loved_age
from loves
left join people p on p.id = loves.id1
left join people p2 on p2.id = loves.id2) t
where t.lover_age < t.loved_age
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/YJFQT8291) is a sample you can play with